# How to solve "no operator "[]" matches these operands" when I use smart pointer

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers

Here is my code:

```
class Mystring
{
private:
    unsigned int size;
    shared_ptr<char>message=make_shared<char>();
public:
    Mystring(const char* input):size(strlen(input)),message(make_shared<char>(size+1))
    {cout<<"Created"<<endl;memcpy(this->message,input,size+1);}
    Mystring(const Mystring& other):size(other.size),message(make_shared<char>(size+1))
    {cout<<"Created"<<endl;memcpy(this->message,other.message,size+1);}
    ~Mystring(){cout<<"Deleted"<<endl;}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& Cout,const Mystring& mystring)
    {Cout<<mystring.message<<endl;return Cout;}
    char& operator[](const unsigned int  index)
    {return this->message[index];}
};
```

I want to use smart pointers and `operator []` properly. How can I solve these problems:

> ```
> no suitable conversion function from "std::shared_ptr<char>" to "void *" exists 
>
> no operator "[]" matches these operands
> ```

Comment: `shared_ptr<char>` is a single char. You want `shared_ptr<char[]>`.

Comment: I tried this. But I got another two problem. "no matching function for call to 'make_shared<char []>(unsigned int)" and "no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, char []>"

Comment: What's your compiler and version? `shared_ptr` for arrays is a new feature. You can also try `unique_ptr<char[]>`, or just use a vector or string.

Comment: I use vscode and latest mingw64.

Comment: Hmm, I thought GCC supported it. Apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

So lots of problems with this code

1. You have a shared char array, so the type is `shared_ptr<char[]>` not `shared_ptr<char>`. This also means you cannot use `make_shared`, since it doesn't work with arrays.
2. If you want to access the pointer to the array use `get()`.
3. Your copy constructor allocates a new array, which is a bit weird since why are you using `shared_ptr`, if you don't want to share the array? On the other hand the default assignment operator will share the array, so you have a strange situation where sometimes when you copy `Mystring` you will share the array, and sometimes you won't.
4. Various other minor issues

Here's a version that works

```
class Mystring
{
private:
    size_t size;
    shared_ptr<char[]> message;
public:
    Mystring(const char* input) : size(strlen(input)), message(new char[size+1])
    {
        cout<<"Created"<<endl;
        memcpy(message.get(), input, size+1);
    }
    Mystring(const Mystring& other): size(other.size), message(other.message)
    {
        cout<<"Created"<<endl;
    }
    ~Mystring()
    {
        cout<<"Deleted"<<endl;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& Cout,const Mystring& mystring)
    {
        Cout<<mystring.message.get()<<endl;return Cout;
    }
    char& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        return message.get()[index];
    }
};
```

I changed the copy constructor so that it does share the underlying array. You can change it back if you wish. However is you want a `Mystring` which does not share it's array with other `Mystring` objects then it would make more sense to use `unique_ptr<char[]>` instead of `shared_ptr`.